# I am not able to start IIS in my PC

Tags: windows, iis

I am not able to start IIS even if I marked all options needed. I have not an idea what is happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What windows 7 version are you running ?

Comment: Windows 7 Home Basic 64bit

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038) because of your OS version.

To start IIS type in cmd

```
net start w3svc
```

Comment: When I typed this command in cmd it shows msg like this: "The requested Service has already been started."

Comment: It means IIS is already running on your pc. If you type "localhost" in your browser, you should see it working.

Comment: It is showing 404 page not found error. Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE".